# My digital clock is not changing time in my emulator

Tags: java, android

My digital clock is not changing time in my emulator.

> How can I possibly code my clock to change it every second?

Here is what I tried:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
a = ("" + mMonth + "/" + mDay + "/" + mYear);
txtDisplay.setText(a);
```

This code doesn't change the time.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: and the php part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display the time, try this.

```
Time time = new Time();
int hour = time.hour;
int min = time.minute;
int sec = time.second;
a = (hour+":"+min+":"+sec);
txtDisplay.setText(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a scheduler like this to schedule when to change the display and then set it like Torcellite showed:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate
      (new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            Time time = new Time();
            int hour = time.hour;
            int min = time.minute;
            int sec = time.second;
            txtDisplay.setText(hour+":"+min+":"+sec);

         }
      }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```